# How to find questions by tag: numpy and NOT python

Tags: support, tags, search, tag-search

I want to retag some questions that have `numpy` but not `python` tags.

I want that:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/numpy+and+python?tab=newest
```

works, then I tried to change the `and` by `no` or `not` without succcess:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/numpy+not+python?tab=newest
```

it makes a group adding the questions with a `no`/`not` tag.

Is it possible to search with `NO`/`NOT`?

Comment: However why - if it has the numpy tagI think that is sufficient as will refer to a particular library which only works under python and for which general python users can't help. If you are going to read the question and only tag those which are python questions and not dependent on numpy and so need the numpy tag removed then I can see the point.

Comment: I did not mean that all the numpy should be tagged as python, it is just a search query to find the possible candidates...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `-` operator in search will do what you want.

So the search would be

> [numpy] -[python]

However, this will only filer posts without the [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag.  You might want to add a wildcard to filter out other variants like [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7) and similar version specific variants.  The wildcard is a `*` and can be used like:

> [numpy] -[python*]

The search URL with the wildcard is:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy+-python+-python-2.7+-python-3.x+-python-imaging-library+-python-sphinx+-python-2.6+-python-idle+-python-requests+-python-2.x+-python-3.3+-python-import+-python-module+-python-2.5+-python-multithreading+-python-c-api+-python-3.2+-pythonpath+-python-2.4+-subprocess+-python-c-extension

Before embarking on a mass retagging spree, keep in mind that edits that do not fix the entire post are strongly discouraged.  If you want to add the tag, go for it, but please make sure there are no other problems (spelling, capitalization, grammar, code formatting) before submitting the edit.

Comment: great point adding the `*`!

Comment: Note that the [python*] wildcard is, somewhat non-intuitively, expanded to exclude the tag [subprocess] in the URL because it is a synonym of [python-subprocess-module].

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-` [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy+-python):

```
[numpy] -[python]
```

Comment: this worked! and the `url` request will be : [`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy+-python`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy+-python)